# ASP.NET System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table control

Tags: asp.net

How can I bind data to a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table - control?

and,

How can I populate it from a List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to a Table webcontrol. If you want to have full control over your HTML you can either use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) (like Jon mentions) or, in ASP.NET 3.0 can you can use the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) control. The latter has a Table template available from Visual Studio. Of course, you could also use the [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) control, which renders as a table. It's probably the easiest to bind data to, but you have a little less control over the rendered output.

To populate it from a List (I presume you mean List?) it simple, you either use an [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx) or bind it manually eg.

```
List<MyData> list = DAL.GetList();
MyControl.DataSource = list;
MyControl.DataBind();
```

Where "MyControl" is the ID of the control you are binding to and "list" is the List (or other enumerable data source) that you wish to bind.

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably be better off using a repeater control for what you're looking for. You can define a `<table>` in the header and a `</table>` in the footer and just `<tr><td></td></tr>` in each item. You can bind from a list in that case.